# WPF - Change Outer Control Opacity Will Not Change Inner Control Opacity

Tags: wpf, background, border, opacity

I have a border1 with full screen and it's Background is #011627. A Grid splits into four part, one of them have border2 and it's Background is #0b192a.

```
 <Border x:Name="border1" Background="#011627"/>
 <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Test" Foreground="White" FontSize="30"/>
     <Border x:Name="border2" Background="#0b192a"/>
 </Grid>
```

[image]

Now I want to set Grid's Opacity to 0.1 and influence text's Opacity, and don't influence border2's Background.

But it doesn't meet my expectation.

```
 <Border x:Name="border1" Background="#011627"/>
 <Grid Opacity="0.1">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Test" Foreground="White" FontSize="30"/>
     <Border x:Name="border2" Background="#0b192a"/>
 </Grid>
```

[image]

Could it happen? Thanks!

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: I want to set Grid's Opacity to 0.1 and influence text's Opacity, and don't influence border2's Background.

Answer (score 1):

[`UIElement.Opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.opacity?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) is by definition applied to all child elements of the (sub)tree, where the root is the element that defines the value.

If you want the to set `Opacity` exclusively to a specific element, you have to set it locally/by `Style` on this very element:

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock Opacity="0.1" Text="Test" />
  <Border x:Name="border2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: oh...so Opacity will apply to all child elements, thanks!